# Adding JavaScript to a Tumblr post

Tags: javascript, tumblr

I'm making a sort of resume website on tumblr to display my work, starting with a small video game I made back in middle school using MIT's Scratch program. I'm using Phosphorus to do this, a website which will take a scratch game and "convert" it to javascript. Included on the phosphorus website is a tool to embed the script into your website's HTML. Here is the code that the tool returned to me.

```
<script src='https://sulfurous.aau.at/js/embed.js?id=125092798&resolution-x=480&resolution-y=360&auto-start=true&light-content=false'></script>
```

The problem is, when I go to put this code into a tumblr post(I'm making sure to switch the text editor to HTML), it doesn't seem to produce a working program. Could anyone offer some help with this, or some other options I could pursue?

Comment: Do you have a link to your blog? Are there any errors being returned in the console. There should be a couple of ways to skin this.

Comment: I think I have it working here: http://madox-test.tumblr.com/phosphorus

Comment: Well done! How'd you get it through?

Comment: I think it worked as it was added to a page (rather than a post). I am not even sure if the post editor allows for html editing any more. I can't see that as an option anyway.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/LxIL4

Comment: It's still an option, but it's been taken off the app and hidden in the settings of the post, accessible through the gear. My script still doesn't seem to work, though.

Comment: Well I did not think this would work in a post but it has: http://madox-test.tumblr.com/post/152998634953/left-beginarraycc-c-1-2-3-br I think you will need to share your tumblr, or report back any errors, as it does seem to be possible. Maybe something else is preventing the js from running?